# Prestashop cross selling module not working

Tags: module, prestashop

I am running prestashop shopping cart and I enabled its cross selling module. After enabling it I could not see any thing on cart saying "customer who bought this product also bought" etc
Is there anything I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've only just enabled this, you won't be getting any information from this module just yet. If no one has purchased similar products since you've enabled this module, there won't be any information gathered just yet.

Give it some time to allow it to gather the data from your customers, right now it likely doesn't have anything to work with but it is working in the background.

Answer (score 1):

The crosselling module needs some orders to check if a product was sold together with other products. A list of 'people who bought this product also bought' will only be shown with products that :
1) are already in any old order AND
2) has other products within that same order.
 
Only if those requirements are met, cross-sold product will be shown.